# Какой путь у asset файла Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-assets

```kotlin
PrintWriter(FileWriter(filename)).use {
                val gson = Gson()
                val jsonString = gson.toJson(newData)
                it.write(jsonString)
```

дерево папки
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я не могу понять, что мне нужно сдеать, чтобы получить путь к test.json или каким-либо другим способом использовать в функции

Comment: Это не файл. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager

Comment: Asset - это ресурс, доступ к нему строго регламентирован. https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/java/read+text+file+from+assets+folder+in+android+studio Тем более вы собрались в него писать, это не разрешается.